# Can I put an HTML button inside the canvas?

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

I want to make the buttons for the game I'm making as real HTML buttons, but they need to be inside the canvas.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Given that the [canvas element](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/the-canvas-element.html#the-canvas-element) has a [transparent content model](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/content-models.html#transparent), it may contain *fallback* elements which are displayed in the event that the `canvas` element is unsupported. They will **not** be displayed if the canvas *is* supported.

You can position HTML elements relative to the canvas' parent to have the buttons "hovering" over the canvas. A [menu element](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/interactive-elements.html#menus) could be an appropriately semantic element to render a list of controls, depending on the context:

<sub>HTML:</sub>

```
<div id="container">
  <canvas id="viewport">
  </canvas>
  <menu id="controls">
  </menu>
</div>
```

<sub>CSS:</sub>

```
#container
{
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
}
#viewport
{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
#controls
{
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Using `menu` is not necessary. You can display almost any HTML element over canvas this way.

Comment: @peci1, I chose `<menu>` for this case because it was semantic, not because it does anything special with regard to `<canvas>`.

Comment: But when i put the canvas in full-screen, the buttons disappears. Is there any way to overcome this?

Answer (score 13):

You can put the button on top of the `canvas` by giving the canvas a `z-index` which is lower than the `z-index` of the button:

```
<canvas style="z-index:1"></canvas>
<input type="button" style="z-index:2; position:absolute; top:x; left:y" value="test"/>
```

where `x` and `y` are numbers.

Comment: I found that this worked in chrome, but for firefox I had to give the canvas a negative z-index.

Answer (score 7):

I don't believe you can 'put' HTML content inside a canvas tag. Whatever you put in there will actually be displayed if the browser *doesn't* support `<canvas>`.

You can, however, position your buttons absolutely over top of a canvas or render areas in your canvas that 'look' like buttons and handle the events yourself (a lot of work).

Comment: You mean whatever you put inside canvas _element_ (not tag) ;)

Answer (score 5):

HTML inside canvas is not possible, but maybe you could position your elements absolutely so that they are "floating" over the canvas, but not inside it.

Answer (score 1):

One way to add button dynamically on the top of the canvas is  following the next two points:
    1. Making zIndex of the button higher than canvas 
    2. Position the button using absolute positioning with desired top and left value

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/n2EYw/398/

HTML:

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="200">           
 </canvas>
```

CSS:

```
canvas {
    border: 1px dotted black;
    background: navy;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
var $testButton = $('<input/>').attr({
    type: 'button',
    name: 'btn1',
    value: 'TestButton',
    id: 'testButton',
    style: 'position:absolute; top:50px;left:100px; zindex:2'
});
$('body').append($testButton);
$(document).on("click", "#testButton", function() {
    alert('button clicked');
});
```

Comment: Hey you added button inside HTML not in canvas.

Answer (score 1):

You can use my [DropdownMenu](https://github.com/anhr/DropdownMenu) for put an HTML button or menu inside the canvas.

[Example](https://github.com/anhr/DropdownMenu#example-button-inside-canvas) of code:

```
<div class="container" id="containerDSE">
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</div>
<script>
var elContainer = document.getElementById( "containerDSE" ),
elCanvas = elContainer.querySelector( 'canvas' );

dropdownMenu.create( [

    {

        name: 'Button',
        onclick: function ( event ) {

            var message = 'Button onclick';
            //console.log( message );
            alert( message )

        },

    },

], {

    elParent: elContainer,
    canvas: elCanvas,
    decorations: 'Transparent',

} );
</script>
```

[Example](https://raw.githack.com/anhr/DropdownMenu/master/Examples/html/) of using.

Answer (score 0):

HTML inside of canvas is not possible.
But if you really want to use buttons, why don't you try positioning the buttons on top of the canvas?

Answer (score 0):

You can put a button inside the canvas (png, jpg, svg and text), using the Canvate library.
http://www.sakuracode.com/canvate

Here you are a sample of a draging button inside the canvas.

```
container.startDrag();
```

https://codepen.io/EiseiKashi/pen/BxNbmj