# How to position some input elements inside an HTML5 canvas element?

Tags: css, html

I have the following page with a black canvas inside of it:

[image]

There, the main menu for a game will be displayed, and it needs to have both a registration and a login form on it. How do I position forms/input elements inside the canvas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [can I put a html button inside the canvas?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797748/can-i-put-a-html-button-inside-the-canvas)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can place HTML elements on top of your canvas by using CSS. See the following post for more info:

[Can I put an HTML button inside the canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797748/can-i-put-a-html-button-inside-the-canvas)

Comment: The question doesn't really have a lot to do with the canvas, I believe any other element could be placed there.

Comment: Ahh gotcha - you could place HTML elements on top of your canvas using CSS. See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797748/can-i-put-a-html-button-inside-the-canvas

Answer (score 2):

You don't. In canvas you'll be handling the rendering of most of your elements.

If you want to use the DOM, you could always overlay those forms/input elements on top of the canvas with a position: absolute or something equivalent. But as for them actually being in the canvas, you're going to have to manually render them. Another poster already put some links down for canvas basics you can make some progress on.

Comment: It's very easy to tell a div to sit on top of a canvas element. Absolute positioning is the simplest way.

Comment: Yep. I wanted to have an element over another element basically. Turns out to be pretty easy.