# buttons on easeljs

Tags: button, easeljs

Im just learning javascript (trying create a game for windows 8 ui).

And this is my button on easeljs, but I think this code too (toooooo) ugly. 
Button must change texture on mouseEvents using one 3x texture of all button states.

Maybe other solution for this purpose?

Using:

```
btn_newgame = new my_controls.Button("button.png", "New Game", "30px sans-serif");
btn_newgame.set_position("center", 300);
btn_newgame.click = function (event) { console.log('newgame click'); };
```

Button code:

```
(function () {

Button.prototype = new createjs.Container();
Button.prototype.constructor = Button;

function Button(source_img, text, font, font_color) {
    this.initialize();
    this.mouseEventsEnabled = true;

    this.set_scale = set_scale;
    this.set_position = set_position;


    text = text || "";
    font = font || "12px sans-serif";
    font_color = font_color || "black";



    this.img_bitmap = new createjs.Bitmap(source_img)
    this.btn_text = new createjs.Text(text, font, font_color);
    this.btn_text.x = source_img.naturalWidth / 2 - this.btn_text.getMeasuredWidth() / 2;
    this.btn_text.y = this.btn_text.getMeasuredHeight() / 8;

    this.addChild(this.img_bitmap);
    this.addChild(this.btn_text);

    this.width = source_img.naturalWidth,
    this.height = source_img.naturalHeight / 4;


    // for different states = different pieces of one texture.
    this.states = {
        out: new createjs.Rectangle(0, 0, this.width, this.height),
        over: new createjs.Rectangle(0, this.height, this.width, this.height),
        down: new createjs.Rectangle(0, this.height * 2, this.width, this.height)
    };

    this.img_bitmap.sourceRect = this.states['out'];


    this.press;
    this.over;
    this.out;
    this.click;

    this.onPress = onPress;
    this.onMouseOver = onMouseOver;
    this.onMouseOut = onMouseOut;
    this.onClick = onClick;

}

function set_scale (scale_x, scale_y) {
    this.scaleX = scale_x || 1;
    this.scaleY = scale_y || 1;
}


function set_position (posX, posY) {

    posX = posX || 0;
    posY = posY || 0;


    if (typeof posX == "number") {
        this.x = posX;
    }
    else {
        switch (posX) {
            case "center":
                this.x = canvas.width / 2 - Math.floor(this.width / 2 * this.scaleX);
                break;
            case "left":
                this.x = 0;
                break;
            case "right":
                this.x = canvas.width - Math.floor(this.width * this.scaleX);
                break;
            default:
                this.x = 0;
        }
    }

    if (typeof posY == "number") {
        this.y = posY;
    }
    else {
        switch (posY) {
            case "center":
                this.y = canvas.height / 2 - Math.floor(this.height / 2 * this.scaleY);
                break;
            case "top":
                this.y = 0;
                break;
            case "bottom":
                this.y = canvas.height - Math.floor(this.height * this.scaleY);
                break;
            default:
                this.y = 0;
        }
    }
}



function onPress (event) {
    this.img_bitmap.sourceRect = this.states['down'];
    this.btn_text.x += 1;
    this.btn_text.y += 1;
    if (this.press)
        this.press(event);
}

function onMouseOver (event) {
    this.img_bitmap.sourceRect = this.states['over'];
    this.last_state = 'over';
    if (this.over)
        this.over(event);
}

function onMouseOut (event) {
    this.img_bitmap.sourceRect = this.states['out'];
    this.last_state = 'out';
    if (this.out)
        this.out(event);
}

function onClick (event) {
    this.img_bitmap.sourceRect = this.states['over'];
    this.btn_text.x -= 1;
    this.btn_text.y -= 1;
    if (this.click)
        this.click(event);
}

my_controls.Button = Button;
})(my_controls); // Button
```

Answer (score 0):

Prototyping the object is a pretty good way to do it, but if you want to avoid this completely you could just add DOM buttons and position them to be part of your UI or create the UI entirely in using DOM.

Related Question:
[Can I put an HTML button inside the canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797748/can-i-put-a-html-button-inside-the-canvas)

All the best,
Shalom