# Dom-like content inside of a html5 canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, canvas

I am developing small game on html5 and there is a need of a tutorial for it, whats the best way to display dom-like content inside of a canvas?
Thanks

Comment: Define 'DOM-like content'...

Comment: Like paragraphs of text, images, buttons etc

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Canvas/Drawing_DOM_objects_into_a_canvas
Stackoverflow question: [Can I put an HTML button inside the canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797748/can-i-put-a-html-button-inside-the-canvas)

Answer (score 0):

There are tons of ways to do this. I would suggest, however, that you choose a game engine instead of trying to build a game from ground zero. Check out this game engine for instance: http://craftyjs.com/