# the image is not showing in the canvas

Tags: javascript, css, html

i need help with image.i put the image in the canvas and it's not working.

```js
setInterval(function(){
    game();
}, 1000/30);
```

```css
#start{
background-color:#33ff00;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>beta</title>
<link href="chip.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>
<canvas height="938" width="1890" id="start"><img src="chio.jpg"/></canvas>
<script src="beta.js"</script>
</body>
</html>
```

i'm lost at this point.

Comment: since canvas can be seen as a drawing table in which you dont simply put elements like you would in a basic DIV you have to use a different approach http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp find some examples here, otherwise look for canvas tutorials, there are plenty

Comment: "Given that the canvas element has a transparent content model, it may contain *fallback* elements which are displayed in the event that the `canvas` element is unsupported. They will **not** be displayed if the canvas *is* supported." -> http://stackoverflow.com/a/4797877/1913729

Answer (score 0):

The canvas element can't have an img child element. If you want to embed a picture file within a canvas element, you have to draw the picture onto the canvas with drawImage().