# Buttons not working on html canvas

Tags: javascript

I am finding it hard to get my buttons working inside a html canvas. I think that the onclick event is not being called or the canvas is over layed and drawing over them but I can't figure out why. I have tried putting the buttons on a higher z-index as demonstrated here

[Can I put an HTML button inside the canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797748/can-i-put-an-html-button-inside-the-canvas)

but I have had no avail. Here is the code for the canvas and button

```
<canvas id="whiteboard" style="z-index:1; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;"></canvas>
<input type="button" style="z-index: 2" value="blue" id="blue" onclick="colorChange('#0000FF');" />
```

here is the script tag

```
<script src="assets/js/color.js"></script>
```

and the function I am trying to call in color.js

`function colorChange(color) {
    alert("adadadsdasd");
    var c = document.getElementById('whiteboard');
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
}`

I am fairly new to JS so I apologise if there is any rookie errors.

Comment: you can't change the z-index of an element unless you set the position to at least relative first. Try adding a position:relative; to the input tag along with the z-index:2;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Behaviour can differ on different browsers, the below works on Firefox and Chrome (note the zindex). Fiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/p9gz8rpm/:

```
<canvas id="whiteboard" style="z-index:-1; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks. However setting it to this means I cant draw on the canvas and buttons now seem to overlay. Can you use z-index with a div so that only that segment is above the canvas?

Comment: Yes, please use the position: tag to do that appropriately (as mentioned in other answer here)

Answer (score 0):

## You forgot to add:

```
position: absolute;
```

to your button. A **z-index only works if it has that set.**

```
<input type="button" style="z-index: 2; position: absolute;" value="blue" id="blue" onclick="colorChange('#0000FF');" />
```

**Edit:**

(*If you don't want to use position: absolute; Use position: relative*)